# Can't get JSON using Volley Library

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm using Volley library to get JSON. I can't load JSON using emulator which runs on Android 2.3, everything just fine with other versions. I have no ideas why it can't get JSON, especially on 2.3 devices.

### JSON Object request:

```
private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        showpDialog();
        final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    extractJSONArray(response.getJSONArray("Accommodation"), "accommodation");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                hidepDialog();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("Error: ", error.getCause().toString());
                error.printStackTrace();
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }
```

### Any ideas?

Comment: Is your web service working? Is it giving the expected response?

Comment: Paste the value of urlJsonObj on a new tab on your navigator and you should see your JSONObject

Comment: Sorry, for misunderstanding, but where is that new tab?

Comment: My bad, I meant to say browser not navigator. On your internet browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.) open a new tab and paste the value of urlJsonObj and press enter

Comment: Oh, yes, everything is good, json looks appropriate on browser. And phone gets json on other Android versions, but it doesn't on 2.3. The link on both is the same, but the result is different.

Comment: log the content of `error.networkResponse.data` to see what you are receiving.

Comment: I have added Log.d("error", error.networkResponse.data.toString()); line and it crashes. My log is here: http://postimg.org/image/tvueek9op/

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all use Gson library it will make your life easier:

And then make POJO of your responses e.g.

```
public class Accommodation {
    public String id;
    public String icon;
    public String name;
    public String nameEn;
    public String type;
    public String fotoLinks;
    public String address;
    public String workHours;
    public String description;
    public String descriptionEn;
    public String votes;
    public String voters;
    public String number;
    public String email;
    public String latitude;
    public String longitude;
}
```

And now combine all pojo classes to match your server response:

```
public class ServerResponse {
    public List<Accommodation> Accommodation;
    public List<CashMachines> Cash_machines; // assuming you have CashMachines as well like above
}
```

And now build a request:

```
Request<ServerResponse> request = new GsonRequest<ServerResponse>(Request.Method.GET, 
     url,AnalyticsData.class, new Response.Listener<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ServerResponse response) {
               // user response here
               Log.d(">>", response.Accommodation.size()+"");
        }, errorListener);
```

and now use this `request`.

Here is [`GsonRequest`](https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples/blob/master/src/com/github/volley_examples/toolbox/GsonRequest.java). Make sure to download gson jar file from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Please note that existing code will immediately start working with this url http://njreteazza.lt.ricina.serveriai.lt/info.php i.e. you don't even need to create pojo classes for all types that are returned just Keep adding pojo classes when you need them.

Comment: Maybe you know why I can't add gson library? Everything seems good but when I try to compile, it gives me UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION, I think somehow it overrides gson library.